# python iterate over a file and replace strings

Tags: python

I'm using the 're' library to replace occurrences of different strings in multiple files. The replacement pattern works fine, but I'm not able to maintain the changes to the files. I'm trying to get the same functionality that comes with the following lines:

```
    with open(KEY_FILE, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        replacements = csv.DictReader(f)
        user_data = open(temp_file, 'r').read()

        for col in replacements:
            user_data = user_data.replace(col[ORIGINAL_COLUMN], col[TARGET_COLUMN])

        data_output = open(f"{temp_file}", 'w')
        data_output.write(user_data)
        data_output.close()
```

The key line here is:

```
user_data = user_data.replace(col[ORIGINAL_COLUMN], col[TARGET_COLUMN])
```

It takes care of updating the data in place using the replace method.

I need to do the same but with the 're' library:

```
    with open(KEY_FILE, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        replacements = csv.DictReader(f)
        user_data = open(temp_file, 'r').read()
        a = open(f"{test_file}", 'w')

        for col in replacements:
            original_str = col[ORIGINAL_COLUMN]
            target_str = col[TARGET_COLUMN]
            compiled = re.compile(re.escape(original_str), re.IGNORECASE)
            result = compiled.sub(target_str, user_data)
            a.write(result)
```

I only end up with the last item in the .csv dict changed in the output file. Can't seem to get the changes made in previous iterations of the for loop to persist.

I know that it is pulling from the same file each time... which is why it is getting reset each loop, but I can't sort out a workaround.

Thanks

Comment: Just as in the first version, you need to assign the result of `sub()` back to the same variable.

Comment: `user_data = compiled.sub(...)`

Comment: And `a.write()` should be after the loop, just like in the first version.

Comment: Why aren't you using `with` for the output files?

Comment: This `open(f"{test_file}", 'w')` is weird as well. Just write `open(test_file, 'w')`.

Comment: @Barmar, good question :) Throwing this together quickly and learning.

Comment: @js-on, totally weird. an artifact from copy paste

Comment: If you use `re.escape()`, there's no difference from using `replace()`. Why do you need to use `re`?

Comment: Using re because I need it to be case-insensitive.

Comment: @Nathan there are string methods such as `.lower()` which return an all lowercase string so case wouldn't matter

Comment: @Matiiss, that would be an extra step I don't really need. I am reading values from a .csv and I don't know if what I'm looking for in the .xml files are upper or lower. If I lower it, then I'd miss something that has one uppercase. I just need it to match regardless and not have to change the string being given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import re
import sys
from io import StringIO

KEY_FILE = '''aaa,bbb
xxx,yyy
'''
TEMP_FILE = '''here is aaa some text xxx
bla bla aaaxxx
'''
ORIGINAL_COLUMN = 'FROM'
TARGET_COLUMN = 'TO'

user_data = StringIO(TEMP_FILE).read()

with StringIO(KEY_FILE) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, ['FROM','TO'])
    for row in reader:
        original_str = row[ORIGINAL_COLUMN]
        target_str = row[TARGET_COLUMN]
        compiled = re.compile(re.escape(original_str), re.IGNORECASE)
        user_data = compiled.sub(target_str, user_data)

sys.stdout.write("modified user_data:\n" + user_data)
```

Some things to note:

- The main problem was `result = sub(..., user_data)` rather than `result = sub(..., result)`. You want to keep updating the same string, rather than always applying to the original.
- The compiling of regex is fairly pointless in this case, since each is just used once.
- I don't have access to your test files, so I used `StringIO` versions inline and printing to stdout; hopefully that's easy enough to translate back to your real code (:

  - In future posts, you might consider doing similar, so that your question has 100% runnable code someone else can try out without guessing.